# In a ASP.NET MVC3 under which folder shall I place my Service layer?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, service-layer, directory-structure

The question is quite straightforward.

In my MVC3 application I have an architecture with **Repository** and **Service** layers, with the Repository exposing its methods to the Service layer and the Service layer exposing its methods to the **Controller**.

The Service layer is a class called `MyServices` that implements a `IMyServices` interface.

In a typical Visual Studio MVC3 folder organization where would you place `MyServices` and `IMyServices`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no rule for that. A `Services` folder seems logical. Or if you are writing a reusable service layer you might put that into a separate class library which you would reference in your ASP.NET MVC application.

Comment: thanks Darin. I was wondering if it was opportune to use the Models folder instead, since the service layer contains business logic hence can be considered as part of the Model together with the repository

Comment: @CiccioMiami, yes, you could use the `Models` folder if you want. But in this case make sure you create a `ViewModels` folder to clearly separate your view models from your domain models.

Comment: That Model folder is for View Models, the best is to put the Services into a different project, this way it's a clearer separation

Comment: @Darin, thanks, I omitted the 'ViewModels' since I thought it was irrelevant. Of course I use the 'ViewModels' to wrap all the data necessary to be passed to the view. However the 'ViewModels' is not linked to the SL but just to the Controller

Comment: @CiccioMiami, I just wanted to insist on the fact that if you use the Models folder for putting your domain logic (domain models and services) you should have a separate folder for your view models.